# How to filter view to pull based on a shared field through taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

We have a two content types: page and article.

Page has 1 field instance field_tag1 that has 10 values. field_tag1 has two separate instances on the article content type (field_tag1_primary and field_tag1_secondary) as taxonomy terms.

Essentially, field_tag1_primary and field_tag1_secondary essentially map to the field_tag1 field instance.

Example of how the relationship work is below.

field_tag1 term values (examples)

1. val1
2. val2
3. val3
4. val4

Basic page1

1. field_tag1 = val1

Article page1

1. field_tag1_primary = val1

Article Page 2
 2. field_tag1_secondary = val1

In the example above, article page 2 and page 1 both are linked to basic page 1 because the field_tag1_primary and field_tag1_secondary values are val1. We have placed a view on the basic page1 that has the following criteria that needs to be meet.

Criteria ("or" condition):
1. if article page1 field_tag1_primary =  basic page1.field_tag1, then return articlepage1
2. if article page2 field_tag1_secondary =  basic page1.field_tag1, then return articlepage1

Current view filters:
1. relationship = where field_tag1 has a value and exists

What we tried that did not work:
1. added contextual filter to take in nid

Comment: This is very hard to follow.  Are you saying that you have a term reference field that is appearing twice on one content type?  Is your problem that you want to use OR relationships between contextual filters?